# tmuxinator initialize pane with multiple commands

Tags: tmux, tmuxinator

I am using Tmuxinator, and I was wondering is there anyway to initialize a Tmux pane using multiple commands?

**Example**

```
panes:
    - vim
    - workon project              #activate virtualenv and ..
      ./manage.py runserver       #run sever
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is supported from 0.6.6.

```
name: sample
root: ~/

windows:
  - stats:
    - ssh stats@example.com
    - tail -f /var/log/stats.log
  - logs:
    layout: main-vertical
    panes:
      - logs:
        - ssh logs@example.com
        - cd /var/logs
        - tail -f development.log
```

Please refer to https://github.com/aziz/tmuxinator#passing-directly-to-send-keys

Answer (score 6):

you could put `&&` between commands.

```
panes:
    - vim
    - workon project &&           #activate virtualenv and ..
      ./manage.py runserver       #run sever
```

Answer (score 3):

For particular using with `virtualenv` and if you don't want to include `workon project &&` in every line, you can use `pre_window`, available from [0.6.0](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#060):

`pre_window: workon project`

Now before running any command, a `workon project` would be called first, allow you to have every new window in virtual environment.