# Is it possible to ssh 2 levels deep in tmux (tmuxinator) init script?

Tags: ssh, tmux, tmuxinator

In order to reach the box I want to be ssh'd into, I need to go through an intermediary box.  Assuming my keys are configured so I don't need to type passwords, is it possible to do something like this?

```
windows:
  - "innerbox": ssh proxybox; ssh innerbox
```

This syntax doesn't work.  I get this output:

```
andersonbd1@localhost:~$ ssh proxybox; ssh innerbox
[andersonbd1@proxybox ~]$
```

It gets me into the first box, but not the second.  If this is not possible in tmuxinator, but is possible in plain tmux, I'd appreciate that answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the answer here:
[tmuxinator initialize pane with multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728102/tmuxinator-initialize-pane-with-multiple-commands)

```
windows:
  - "innerbox": 
    - ssh proxybox
    - ssh innerbox
```